# how can one use the output generated by microphone of a python file as input for the java file?

Tags: python, redirect, standards

Hell0 everyone I am using a cloudspeech API and with the help of a microphone I am getting a output of the spoken words as output in the python file. I want to use this output as input for a java file. Is there any way out by which I can link the output of the python as input of the java file??

```
import os
import aiy.audio
import aiy.cloudspeech
import aiy.voicehat


def main():
    recognizer = aiy.cloudspeech.get_recognizer()

    button = aiy.voicehat.get_button()
    led = aiy.voicehat.get_led()
    aiy.audio.get_recorder().start()

    while True:
        print('Press the button and speak')
        button.wait_for_press()
        print('Listening...')
        text = recognizer.recognize()
        if text is None:
            print('Sorry, I did not hear you.')
        else:
            if 'goodbye' in text:
                os._exit(0)
text = recognizer.recognize()
print('You said "', text, '"')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

in this the text output I want to use it as a input in my java program.

Answer (score 0):

You're unclear on how the Java program normally accepts text, but here are a couple of possible solutions:

- Write the text to a file and then read the input from the Java file.
- If the Java script isn't already running, launch it using the `subprocess` module and pass the string as a commandline argument.
- If your Java program already has other ways that it imports text, simply interface using those methods.